# getting unexpected results out of Java ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a code for an special case of hanoi towers , and now I have this problem that suddenly emerged out of nowhere !

Well , to have said it easily , the objects that I add to my arraylist do not match the objects that are in the arraylist !

I'm posting my code here , and I know it is long , but I have written a comment above the line where the problem is happening :

```
    import java.io.* ;
import java.util.* ;

class Tools
{
    public static ArrayList<Integer> refinedSplit(String line) // this function basically splits a String by " " and throws the garbage out
    {
        String[] args = line.split(" ") ;
        ArrayList<Integer> returnValue = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++ )
            if ( !args[i].equals(" ") && !args[i].equals("") )
                returnValue.add(Integer.parseInt(args[i])) ;
        return returnValue ;
    }
    public static final Integer numOfPegs = 3 ;
};

class Hanoi
{
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pegs ;
    protected static Integer biggestTower ;
    protected static Integer minOfMoves ;
    protected static Integer d0 ;
    protected static Integer k0 ;
    protected static Integer[] pegIndex ;
    protected static Integer[] goalIndex ;
    protected static void pegIndexSetter ()
    {
        pegIndex = new Integer[biggestTower+1] ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < pegs.size() ; i++ )
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < (pegs.get(i)).size() ; j++ )
                pegIndex[(pegs.get(i)).get(j)] = i ;
    }
    public Integer getMinOfMoves () { return minOfMoves ; }
    protected static void goalIndexSetter( Integer n )
    {
        if ( n.equals(biggestTower) )
        {
            goalIndex[n] = pegIndex[n] ;
            return ;
        }
        goalIndexSetter( n + 1 ) ;
        if ( pegIndex[n+1] == goalIndex[n+1] )
            goalIndex[n] = goalIndex[n+1] ;
        else
            goalIndex[n] = 3 - pegIndex[n+1] - goalIndex[n+1] ;
    }
    protected static void determiner()
    {
        Integer k = pegIndex[biggestTower] ;
        double a = biggestTower ;
        minOfMoves = (int)Math.pow(2 , a) - 1 ;
        for ( int d = biggestTower ; d > 0 ; d-- )
        {
            if ( pegIndex[d].equals(k) )
            {
                a = d - 1 ;
                minOfMoves = minOfMoves - (int)Math.pow(2 , a ) ;
            }
            else 
            {
                d0 = d ;
                k0 = k ;
                k = 3 - pegIndex[d] - k ;
            }
        }

    }
    public static ArrayList<Integer> unYekiPeg ( Integer a , Integer b )
    {
        for ( Integer i = 0 ; i < Tools.numOfPegs ; i++ )
            if ( !i.equals(a) && !i.equals(b) )
                return pegs.get(i) ;
        return new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
    }
    //protected static void save ( void ) ;
    protected static void move ( ArrayList<Integer> from , ArrayList<Integer> to )
    {
        if ( from.size() != 0 )
        {
            to.add(from.get(from.size()-1)) ;
            from.remove(from.size()-1) ;
        }
    }
    protected void sortMessedUpHanoi ( ArrayList<Integer> from , ArrayList<Integer> to , ArrayList<Integer> using , Integer n )
    {
        System.out.println("shitfacemotherfucker") ;
        if ( n.equals(d0) )
        {
            System.out.println("SHIIIIIIIT") ;
            move(from,to) ;
            return ;
        }
        if ( !pegIndex[n].equals(goalIndex[n]) ) 
        {
            System.out.println("SHIt") ;
            sortMessedUpHanoi(from,to,using,n-1) ;
            Hanoi.move(pegs.get(pegIndex[n]),pegs.get(goalIndex[n])) ;
            sortMessedUpHanoi(using,to,from,n-1) ;
        }
        else
            sortMessedUpHanoi(from,to,using,n-1) ;
    }
    public void sort()
    {
        sortMessedUpHanoi(pegs.get(pegIndex[biggestTower]),pegs.get(goalIndex[biggestTower]),unYekiPeg(pegIndex[biggestTower],goalIndex[biggestTower]),biggestTower) ;
    }
    public void print () 
    {
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < pegs.size() ; i++ )
            for ( int j = (pegs.get(i)).size()-1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
                System.out.println((pegs.get(i)).get(j)) ;
    }
    public Hanoi ( ArrayList<String> _pegs , Integer max ) // aman az input e sarekari !
    {
        pegs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>() ;
        Integer[] firstIndex = new Integer[Tools.numOfPegs] ;
        Integer[] lastIndex = new Integer[Tools.numOfPegs] ;
        Integer counter = 0 ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < (_pegs.get(_pegs.size()-1)).length() ; i++ )
        {
            if ( counter == Tools.numOfPegs )
                break ;
            if ( (_pegs.get(_pegs.size()-1)).charAt(i) != ' ' )
            {
                firstIndex[counter] = i ;
                while ( i < (_pegs.get(_pegs.size()-1)).length() && (_pegs.get(_pegs.size()-1)).charAt(i) != ' ' )
                    i++ ;
                lastIndex[counter] = i ;
                counter++ ;
            }
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Tools.numOfPegs ; i++ )
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> tempArray = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
            for ( int j = _pegs.size() - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j-- )
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;
                if ( lastIndex[i] < (_pegs.get(j)).length() )
                    temp = Tools.refinedSplit((_pegs.get(j)).substring(firstIndex[i],lastIndex[i])) ;
                else if ( firstIndex[i] < (_pegs.get(j)).length() )
                    temp = Tools.refinedSplit((_pegs.get(j)).substring(firstIndex[i])) ;
                if ( temp.size() == 0 )
                    break ;
                else if ( (temp.get(0)).equals(0) )
                {
                    pegs.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()) ;
                    break ;
                }
                else if ( temp.get(0) <= max )
                    tempArray.add(temp.get(0)) ;
            }
            pegs.add(tempArray) ;
        }
        biggestTower = max ;
        pegIndexSetter() ;
        goalIndex = new Integer[biggestTower+1] ;
        goalIndexSetter(1) ;
        determiner() ;
        /*//testing bitch
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------") ;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < goalIndex.length ; i++ )
            System.out.println("disk no : "+i+" goalIndex is : "+goalIndex[i]) ;
        System.out.println("d0 is : " + d0 + " and k0 is : " + k0+ " and min of moves is : " + minOfMoves ) ;
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------") ;
        //end of testing bitch*/
    }
    public Hanoi ( ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> _pegs )
    {
        pegs = _pegs ;
    }
    public Hanoi () {}
};

public class MessedUpHanoi
{
    public static ArrayList<Hanoi> readAndParseInput () 
    {
        //reading raw input
        ArrayList<String> tempDecks = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        while ( reader.hasNextLine() ) 
        {
            tempDecks.add(reader.nextLine()) ;
        }
        Integer numOfDecks = Integer.parseInt(tempDecks.get(0)) ;
        // from this line , I'm trying to separate my Hanois !!
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> decks = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>() ;
        Integer bookmark[] = new Integer[numOfDecks] ;
        Integer counter = 0 ;
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < tempDecks.size()-1 ; i++ )
        {
            if ( counter == numOfDecks )
                break ;
            if ( (Tools.refinedSplit(tempDecks.get(i))).get(0) >= (Tools.refinedSplit(tempDecks.get(i+1))).get(0) && (Tools.refinedSplit(tempDecks.get(i))).size() == 1  )
            {
                bookmark[counter] = i ;
                counter++ ;
            }
        }

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < bookmark.length ; i++ )
        {
            ArrayList<String> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<String>() ;
            if ( i == bookmark.length - 1 )
            {
                for ( int j = bookmark[i]+1 ; j < tempDecks.size() ; j++ )
                    tempArrayList.add(tempDecks.get(j)) ;
            }
            else
            {
                for ( int j = bookmark[i]+1 ; j < bookmark[i+1] ; j++ )
                    tempArrayList.add(tempDecks.get(j)) ;
            }
            decks.add(tempArrayList) ;
        }
        //end of separation of Hanois
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < decks.size() ; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < (decks.get(i)).size() ; j++ )
                System.out.println("\"" + (decks.get(i)).get(j) + "\"") ;
            System.out.println("___________________") ;
        }
        //now converting every deck to a Hanoi instance
        ArrayList<Hanoi> returnValue = new ArrayList<Hanoi>() ;
        // the problem is here **************************************************************************
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < decks.size() ; i++ )
        {
            Hanoi h = new Hanoi(decks.get(i),(Tools.refinedSplit(tempDecks.get(bookmark[i]))).get(0)) ;
            h.print() ;
            returnValue.add(h) ;
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < returnValue.size() ; i++ )
            (returnValue.get(i)).print() ;
        return returnValue ;
        // till here *******************************************************************************
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        System.out.println("This program is designed to sort messed up Hanois") ;
        ArrayList<Hanoi> badHanoi = readAndParseInput() ;
        if ( args.length != 0 )
        {
            if ( args[0].equals("-n") )
            {
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < badHanoi.size() ; i++ )
                    System.out.println((badHanoi.get(i)).getMinOfMoves()) ;
            }
        }
        /*for ( int i = 0 ; i < badHanoi.size() ; i++ )
        {
            (badHanoi.get(i)).sort() ;
            (badHanoi.get(i)).print() ;
        }*/
    }
};
```

with the following input , I'm not getting what I expect !!!
could someone please tell me what's wrong ?

edit : the problem is here :

```
ArrayList<Hanoi> returnValue = new ArrayList<Hanoi>() ;
// the problem is here **************************************************************************
for ( int i = 0 ; i < decks.size() ; i++ )
{
    Hanoi h = new Hanoi(decks.get(i),(Tools.refinedSplit(tempDecks.get(bookmark[i]))).get(0)) ;
    h.print() ;
    returnValue.add(h) ;
}
for ( int i = 0 ; i < returnValue.size() ; i++ )
    (returnValue.get(i)).print() ;
return returnValue ;
// till here *******************************************************************************
```

}

you see , I once print the objects I want to add to arraylist before adding them , and once after that , and the results are different , which shouldnt be !

sample input :

2

10

1

2   4  3

7   5  6

10  8  9

4

2

3 1   4

sample out put :

"1"

"2  4  3"

"7  5  6"

"10  8  9"

---

"2"

"3 1   4"

---

1

2

7

10

4

5

8

3

6

9

2

3

1

4

// the output for the first printing , and the rest is the output for the second printing , and they are different as you see

2

3

1

4

2

3

1

4

p.s. : I have tested all the parsing units in my program and the problem happens in the start commented area !!! and by the way all the lines in input are in one column , I couldn’t fix it here !

Comment: You can use `if ( !args[i].isEmpty() )` instead of `if ( !args[i].equals(" ") && !args[i].equals("") )`

Comment: plz excuse my anger , the deadline is in like 4 hours and I'm getting this bug outa nowhere !

Comment: Can you explain better what is your problem with an example? because I'm not going to compile and execute the code to figure it out.

Comment: @RamonBoza He *did* give an example output.

Comment: and by the way , the output is formatted correctly , the input has a problem !

Comment: In what sense is the input a problem?

Comment: @RamonBoza the problem is that it should print this twice 1

2

7

10

4

5

8

3

6

9

2

3

1

4
instead of printing it once and then for the second time printing something else !

Comment: I editted the text , is it good now ?

Comment: @AshkanKzme I understand the pressure of being under a deadline, but please remember everyone here is volunteering their time - for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that all your `Hanoi` attributes are static. Hence, they’re shared among all instances of `Hanoi`. That is, each time you do `new Hanoi(something, somethingElse)` you effectively destroy the previously created `Hanoi`.

You need to remove the `static` keyword from some (if not all) of your `Hanoi` attributes.

You can have more information about the `static` keyword in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) from Sun/Oracle.